# Cannot iterate through a Template List C++

Tags: c++, list, templates, iterator

I'm new to using Templates in C++, and I'm trying to get iterate through a Template list.

Here is my code

```
template <typename T>
void pleaseWork(const list<T>& aList, list<T>& list1, list<T>& list2) 
{
typename list<T>::iterator i;
int n = 0;
for(i = aList.begin(); i != aList.end(); ++i) {
         //Do something crazy
         n++;
}

}

int main()
{
    list<int> lista;
    list<int> list1;
    list<int> list2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        lista.push_back(i*2);
    }

    pleaseWork(lista, list1, list2);

return 0; 
}
```

When I compile I get the following error: 
error: no match for ‘operator=’ in `i = ((const std::list<int, std::allocator<int> >*)aList)->std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin` with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator’

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aList` is a reference-to-`const`, so `begin()` will return a `const_iterator`.

Use `auto` if your compiler supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing `pleaseWork` a reference to a `const` list, you need to use a `const_iterator` to access its contents.